# How to use TOP N WITH TIES alongside COUNT

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've been trying to adapt other answers here for ages without success, so here goes... I have a basic query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @tbl_counts 
ORDER BY
    sgId,
    CategoryCount DESC,
    qccId;
```

This shows the following results:

```
sgId    qccId    CategoryCount
------- -------- -------------
4668    18        8
4668    77        7
4668    2         6
4669    43        2
4669    46        2
4670    25        3
4670    27        3
4670    74        2
4671    56        4
4671    60        3
4671    74        3
4671    54        3
4671    55        3
4671    78        2
4671    88        1
4671    89        1
4671    90        3
```

I need to amend this query to show the following:

For each unique `sgId` value, show the top 3 `CategoryCount` values (with ties if they exist), and the appropriate `qccId` value.  Therefore, the results should be:

```
sgId    qccId CategoryCount
------- ----- -------------
4668    18    8
4668    77    7
4668    2     6     -- top 3 4668
4669    43    2     
4669    46    2     -- top 2 4669 because only 2 existed
4670    25    3     
4670    27    3     
4670    74    2     -- top 3 4670
4671    56    4     
4671    60    3     
4671    74    3     
4671    54    3     
4671    55    3     -- top 5 4671 caused by TIES, but discards others
```

Usually I would ROW_NUMBER here, but am struggling because it doesn't present TIES (I don't think).  Therefore on adapting other answers I've found, I've got this far but it doesn't work properly...

```
SELECT
    cnt.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        sgId
    FROM
        @tbl_counts) sg INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES
        *
    FROM
        @tbl_counts
    ORDER BY
        CategoryCount DESC) cnt ON cnt.sgId = sg.sgId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like the perfect job for the window function `DENSE_RANK`:

```
;WITH
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT      *,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sgId ORDER BY CategoryCount DESC) As RowRank
        FROM        @tbl_counts
    )

SELECT      *
FROM        cte
WHERE       RowRank <= 3
ORDER BY    sgId, CategoryCount DESC, qccId
```

Comment: Wow.  I never even knew that this existed.  Works like a charm.  I'm off to study the documentation, but for others, this summarises how amazing this is here https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` as you proposed in title:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM @tbl_counts
ORDER BY 
   IIF(DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sgId ORDER BY CategoryCount DESC)<=3,0,1);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/WYJEK65755)**</kbd>